# In Python, is there a way to update a container using the foreach-style construct?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, foreach, containers

I assumed that the foreach-style construct in `Python` would allow me to update my list like it does in `C#`. It doesn't.

After some investigation, I discovered that the variable used in `Python` in the foreach-style construct is not a reference but rather a separate scalar variable, so I can't update my container using that. Is there a way to update the container using the foreach-style?

Here is some code that demonstrates my question:

```
inputString = "   Type X Widgets  ,  25, 14.20 ,  Type Y Widgets , 4  , 1.12 "
inputList = inputString.split(',')
print(inputList) # Now I need to get rid of whitespace on the ends of each element

# The foreach-style does NOT update inputList
for element in inputList:
    element = element.strip()
    print(element, end=",") # element contains the stripped string as I wanted
print()
print(inputList) # the whitespace on the ends of the elements is still there

# The for-style with subscripts DOES update inputList
for i in range(len(inputList)):
    inputList[i] = inputList[i].strip()
    print(inputList[i], end=",") # inputList[i] contains the stripped string as I wanted
print()
print(inputList) # it finally contains the stripped strings with no whitespace on the ends
```

Here's the output for the above:

```
['   Type X Widgets  ', '  25', ' 14.20 ', '  Type Y Widgets ', ' 4  ', ' 1.12 ']
Type X Widgets,25,14.20,Type Y Widgets,4,1.12,
['   Type X Widgets  ', '  25', ' 14.20 ', '  Type Y Widgets ', ' 4  ', ' 1.12 ']
Type X Widgets,25,14.20,Type Y Widgets,4,1.12,
['Type X Widgets', '25', '14.20', 'Type Y Widgets', '4', '1.12']
```

The first for loop does not update the container. The second one does. In this simple case, it doesn't matter much that I would have to use subscripts, but I would really like to be able to use the foreach-style to update more complex types of containers when a subscript simply won't do.

I can do this in `C#`, and it's a very powerful tool used that way. Is this possible in `Python` by doing something in addition to what I tried in the first loop? (If so, I would imagine it would involve using pointers. Does `Python` even have pointers?)

Comment: "I can do this in Java and C#, and it's a very powerful tool used that way" - I don't know for sure about C#, but you definitely can't do it in Java.

Comment: Apparently you can in C#, [by declaring the loop variable with `ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

Comment: Python does not have pointers. It would be helpful if you gave an example of more complex types of containers, but in any case, you will *always* need to use a mutator method to mutate an object. Assignment in python never mutates. So perhaps it would be more helpful if you gave an example of the container that you had in mind, and we can show you the Pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: "I discovered that the variable used in Python in the foreach-style construct is not a reference but rather a separate scalar variable" I'm not sure what you mean by "a separate scalar variable" as opposed to a reference, but Python variables act like references (i.e. they do not create copies on assignment)

Comment: This is absolutely essential reading for people coming to Python from languages like C, btw: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html It is written by a StackOverflow legend, Ned Batchelder. But, if coming from C, you can actually think of Python variables like pointers to PyObject structs, except you cannot directly dereference them, and the only way to mutate them is to use methods on those PyObject's. Indeed, you can think of `some_object[i] = x` as syntactic sugar for `some_object.__setitem__(i, x)`

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, I might be using incorrect terminology, but what I'm trying to say is that element is a separate variable that no longer has anything to do with the list. Are you saying that the variable element did not get assigned a copy of each of the elements in the list? If not, then wouldn't it have to be by reference, which it certainly appears that it is not. Not shown in this code, I printed element at the bottom of the loop, and it was stripped like I wanted. It just didn't go back into the list. I'll add that part back to the code. It might help show what I mean.

Comment: @megaritzmom the elements *are definitely not copied*, but they are assigned to new variables. Again, please read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html it is especially useful to people coming from lower-level languages. Python's variables are quite simple, but they may not behave the way C programmers expect

Comment: Again, `element = element.strip()` simply takes `element`, which at first refers to the same object that is in your list, then creates a *new object* with `str.strip` (since strings are immutable, their methods always return new objects) and then that gets assigned to the variable `element`. But this never mutates your original list.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not what you want, but an easy way would be to create a new list, like this:

```
inputList = [
    element.strip()
    for element in inputList]
```

This assigns the new list to the same variable, replacing the old one (the old one will be garbage-collected some time after this).

The downside is, that this doubles the amount of used memory; once the above statement is done, the old list can be garbage-collected, but there will still be a spike in memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you can't.  That's because you're *reassigning* the object to a new reference instead.

In a "foreach" type of iteration like this:

```
for element in inputList:
```

You are iterating through the *object of the element itself* within the list.  But in this case, it's a `str` object, which is immutable.  i.e. when you try to assign this line:

```
element = element.strip()
```

You are reassigning *element* with the *new* object from stripped content of the original.  Since it's a new object, it is no way related to the `inputList` itself.

In the second example however, you are now iterating through a *list of indices* based on `inputList`:

```
for i in range(len(inputList)):
# range(len(inputList)) -> range(0, 6)
```

As you iterate through the list, notice you are reassigning the specific index of `inputList` again:

```
inputList[i] = inputList[i].strip()
```

This assigns a *new* object back to `inputList[i]`.  It is no longer the same `str` object that you once had in the list.

Having said that, in other use cases, the "foreach" that you are looking for works just fine, *as long as the object is mutable*.  Observe this following example:

```
lst = [[] for _ in range(5)]
lst
# [[], [], [], [], []]
for i in lst:
    i.append('foo')

lst
# [['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]
```

Note the difference here: `i` is not *reassigned*, but directly changed by the `append()` method.  To further prove that `i` is a direct object reference per your expectation, if I did this *after the iteration is finished*:

```
i.append('bar')
lst
# [['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo', 'bar']]

id(i)
# 61353816
id(lst[-1])
# 61353816
```

See how the *last* element of `lst` is now appended.  That's because `i` still retains the reference.  The `id()` also shows the definitive proof of what you're asking.

If I were to write the iteration like this:

```
for i in lst:
    i = ['foo']

lst
# [[], [], [], [], []]
id(i)
# 61354112 <-- different obj id
id(lst[-1])
# 61353816
```

It would no longer work for the same reason your example didn't.  Because `i` has now been reassigned to a new object instead of the direct object reference within the iteration.  Notice the difference in object id.

Answer (score -2):

Hhm. In a **for loop**, during each iteration, your variable (in your case *element*) will be assigned to a copy of the next value (object) in your list  and not to reference of this value (object). (Which is not completely correct, but you know what I'm trying to say). So to solve your project, you could maybe do something like this:

```
for element in inputList:
    inputList[inputList.index(element)] = element.strip()
print(inputList)
```

Please note, that this will not work when there is the same element in your list twice.

Hope it helped!

Comment: This is dangerous and absurdly inefficient for no benefit.

Comment: This introduces quadratic-time behavior for no good reason. Just use `enumerate` or even `range(len(...))`

Comment: `element` is *not* a copy of the object.  It *is* the direct object reference of `inputList` elements.  The reference just changes upon reassignment, i.e. `element = ...`.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I'm trying to avoid subscripts. If I have to use them, the 2nd way in my code seems much better than this.